# Accordion second level overlaps first

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am struggling getting my accordion to work. When I collapse the first level, the second one comes up as it should, but it then the first level is still visible.

Accordion, not collapsed:

[image]

Accordion collapsed:

[image]

I've been staring at this for hours. Probably I am missing something stupid here.

```html
<div class='accordion' id='mainAccordion'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header' id='headingOt'>
      <h2 class='mb-0'>
        <button aria-controls='collapseOt' aria-expanded='true' class='btn btn-link' data-target='#collapseOt' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
          <h2>Header</h2>
        </button>
        <div aria-labelledby='headingOt' class='collapse show' data-parent='#mainAccordion' id='collapseOt'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            dummy text
          </div>
        </div>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header' id='heading-nt'>
      <h2 class='mb-0'>
        <button aria-controls='collapseNt' aria-expanded='false' class='btn btn-link' data-target='#collapseNt' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
          <h2>header</h2>
        </button>
        <div aria-labelledby='headingNt' class='collapse show' data-parent='#mainAccordion' id='collapseNt'>
          <div class='card-body'>
            dummy text
          </div>
        </div>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

------------------ Addition, 5 feb 2019 ------------
Attached a little gif that shows what happens. It seems that the accordion works well, it collapses the text below, the second header shifts up, but then the first text pops up again.
[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Everything works fine.

Comment: OK, then the problem is probably somewhere else. I'll double check my config. Maybe there's something wrong there